# GroveGPS to raspberry pi

Tags: gps

My raspberry pi is Raspberry Pi Rev 2 Model B 512MB made in UK.
Use GrovrPi not grovepi+.
I try to use them with Grove – GPS. And I run the program which copy form https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/blob/master/Software/Python/grove_gps/README.md

But value is empty. 
Please tell how can I do.

[image]

Comment: What kind of gps module are you using and how is it connected?

Comment: I use this GPS and plug Grove GPS into grovepi socket RPISER.
http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_GPS

Comment: Can you please show us a wiring diragram for your grovrpi?

Comment: I discover that I run the program ir_receiver_check.py
The result is false
Is the program  right?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4d_j5X02MGjRFdZMjdKd0ZUSVk/view?usp=sharing 
This is my grovepi and plug Grove GPS into grovepi socket RPISER.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4d_j5X02MGjcXFfdzFlS1JYWUE/view?usp=sharing
This is ir_receiver_check.py